# Add 1px to padding of element with jquery

Tags: jquery

How do I add 1px to the padding of a div element with jquery?  The div element might have any amount of padding beforehand, and I want to increment the padding by 1px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the old value, add one pixel to it, and assign it as the new value:

```
obj.css("padding", parseInt(obj.css("padding"))+1)
```

If your former padding value is not in pixels you will probably do some conversion first.

Comment: this didn't work for me, but if instead of saying "padding", I did "paddingTop" etc, then it worked :)